# Java For Loop, Input Number of Scores

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am beginner in Java programming and I need to indicate the number of scores before the program enters a for loop. Here is an example:

If I enter '4' as the input it will declare enter score 4 times and will get the average.

Trial code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Exer2{
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String strinput;

int i;
int x;
x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

System.out.print("Enter number or scores here:");
x = input.nextInt();

for (i = 0; i < x; i++){
    System.out.print("Enter score here:");
    if (i==0){
        strinput = input.readLine();
        x=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
    }

}

i=(a+b+c)/x;
System.out.println("The average score is " +i);
```

Comment: Smells like homework.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can read the number of scores similar to the way you read each individual score. I also suggest that you use an array rather than name the variables.

Comment: i'd say x=input.readline() is what you want, but hard to say what you really want

Comment: how will i indicate x as number of times in looping, I dont know what to start

Comment: You will need to take in the user's input for number of scores, store it in `x`, and then use `x` as the limiter in your `for` loop.

Comment: right now, your loop will loop 20 times. Try thinking it through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comment, I was able to understand the question.

> how will i indicate x as number of times in looping, I dont know what to start

To save the input from the user:

```
System.out.print("Enter # of scores:");
x = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
```

Then in your loop:

```
int scores = 0; //This will hold the sum of the scores
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter score " + i + ": "); //Ask for new score
        scores = scores + Integer.parseInt(input.readLine()); //Add score to existing sum of previous scores
    }
    System.out.println("The average score is " + scores / x); // Gets the average score and prints to console
```

Comment: I fixed it. 'i' needed to start at 1 in the loop, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read your input, use

```
x = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
```

maybe after renaming your variables (x not really explicit)